# Incorrect output in Dijkstra's implementation

Tags: algorithm

I am trying to implement Dijkstra's algorithm using adjacency list and priority queue but getting incorrect output for some of the vertices. Since there is no decreaseKey method in inbuilt priority queue in Java I am adding the new vertex (with updated distance from source). Can anyone advise where am I mistaken ? My code is :

```
class Graph3 {
    private int V;
    private ArrayList<Integer> adj [];
    Map<String, Integer> weight; //for O(1) lookup of edge weight
    PriorityQueue<Vertex> minHeap;
    int d [];
    int p[];
    boolean visited [];
    Graph3(int n) {
        this.V = n;
        adj = new ArrayList[n];
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
            adj[i] = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        }
        weight = new HashMap<String, Integer> ();
        minHeap = new PriorityQueue<Vertex>(n, new Vertex());
        visited  = new boolean[n];
        Arrays.fill(visited, false);
        p = new int[n];
        Arrays.fill(p, -1);
        d = new int[n];
        Arrays.fill(d,Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    }
    public void addEdge(int a, int b, int w) {
        adj[a].add(b);
        weight.put(a+","+b,w); //cost of edge(a,b)
    }

    public void calculateShortest(int source) {
        d[source] = 0;  
        visited[source] = true;
        for(int i=0; i<V; i++) minHeap.offer(new Vertex(i,d[i]));
        while(!minHeap.isEmpty()) {
            Vertex u = minHeap.poll();
            relaxEdges(u); //relax all outgoing edges of u
        }
        for(int i=0; i<d.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Shortest path from "+source+" to vertex "+i+" = "+d[i]); 
        }
    }

   public void relaxEdges(Vertex u) {      
       for(int i: adj[u.getName()]) {
           if(!visited[i]) {
               int alt = d[u.getName()] + weight.get(u.getName()+","+i);
               if(d[i] > alt) {
                   d[i] =  alt;
                   Vertex temp = new Vertex(i,d[i]);
                   minHeap.offer(temp);
                   p[i] = u.getName();
                   visited[i] = true;
               }
           }
       }
   }   
}
//to be used for binding every vertex with dval for use in PQ
class Vertex implements Comparator<Vertex> {
    int name;
    int dval;  //current min distance from source
    public Vertex() {

    }
    public Vertex(int name, int dval) {
        this.name = name;
        this.dval = dval;
    }
    public int getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(int name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getDval() {
        return dval;
    }
    public void setDval(int dval) {
        this.dval = dval;
    }
    public int compare(Vertex a, Vertex b) {
        return (a.dval - b.dval);
    }   
}
public class DijkstraShortestPath {

  public static void main(String args []) {
      Graph3 g = new Graph3(9);
        g.addEdge(0, 1, 4);
        g.addEdge(0, 7, 8);
        g.addEdge(1, 2, 8);
        g.addEdge(1, 7, 11);
        g.addEdge(2, 3, 7);
        g.addEdge(2, 8, 2);
        g.addEdge(2, 5, 4);
        g.addEdge(3, 4, 9);
        g.addEdge(3, 5, 14);
        g.addEdge(4, 5, 10);
        g.addEdge(5, 6, 2);
        g.addEdge(6, 7, 1);
        g.addEdge(6, 8, 6);
        g.addEdge(7, 8, 7);

        g.calculateShortest(0);
  }
}
**My Output :**
Shortest path from 0 to vertex 0 = 0
Shortest path from 0 to vertex 1 = 4
Shortest path from 0 to vertex 2 = 12
Shortest path from 0 to vertex 3 = 19
Shortest path from 0 to vertex 4 = 28
Shortest path from 0 to vertex 5 = 16
Shortest path from 0 to vertex 6 = 18
Shortest path from 0 to vertex 7 = 8
Shortest path from 0 to vertex 8 = 15
**Correct Output :** 
Shortest path from 0 to vertex 0 = 0
Shortest path from 0 to vertex 1 = 4
Shortest path from 0 to vertex 2 = 12
Shortest path from 0 to vertex 3 = 19
Shortest path from 0 to vertex 4 = 21
Shortest path from 0 to vertex 5 = 11
Shortest path from 0 to vertex 6 = 9
Shortest path from 0 to vertex 7 = 8
Shortest path from 0 to vertex 8 = 14
```

Answer (score 0):

Something that is off is that you set `visited[i] = true` for all neighboring nodes that get updated in `relaxEdges`. Dijkstra's algorithm always only sets the currently processed node to visited, not the neighbors. I would guess that this is why you get incorrect output. Delete this line and instead add `visited[u.getName()] = true` in the while loop.

Since you add nodes multiple times to the queue, you should also directly test against `visited[u.getName()]` in the while-loop so nodes do not get processed multiple times.

Then, you assign to `p[i]`, but never use it.

And lastly, I advice to have an `Edge` class because representing edges as string-concatenated integers sure is clunky.